# XSLT: select node based on the value of many attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XSLT that's used to parse a XML into a json. I pasting below the part I'm trying to retrieve the data from:

```
<datafield tag="856" ind1="4" ind2="0">
    <subfield code="u">abc</subfield>
</datafield>
<datafield tag="856" ind1="4" ind2="2">
    <subfield code="u">xyz</subfield>
</datafield>
```

I want to select the data from the node where `tag=856 AND ind1=4 AND ind2=2`

I managed to do the check if this node exists, but I'm getting the value of both nodes with the following rule:

```
<xsl:if test="marc:datafield[@tag='856'] and marc:datafield[@ind1='4'] and marc:datafield[@ind2='2']">
    <z:index name="thumbnailUrl_s Thumbnail">
        <xsl:value-of select="marc:datafield[@tag='856']/marc:subfield[@code='u']"/>
    </z:index>
</xsl:if>
```

Is there a way so my `xsl:value-of` returns only the node matching the rules I described above? I've been looking on similar answers here in StackOverflow and so far I couldn't find one with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
<xsl:if test="marc:datafield[@tag='856' and @ind1='4' and @ind2='2']">
    <z:index name="thumbnailUrl_s Thumbnail">
        <xsl:value-of select="marc:datafield[@tag='856' and @ind1='4' and @ind2='2']/marc:subfield[@code='u']"/>
    </z:index>
</xsl:if>
```

Or, in a template:

```
<xsl:template match="marc:datafield[@tag='856' and @ind1='4' and @ind2='2']">
    <z:index name="thumbnailUrl_s Thumbnail">
        <xsl:value-of select="marc:subfield[@code='u']"/>
    </z:index>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! The first option works perfectly in my case. This index is inside a xsl:when, so I can't use the template. But the first option worked just fine =]

Comment: Have you understood what you did wrong? Your condition `marc:datafield[@tag='856'] and marc:datafield[@ind1='4']` tests "if there is a data field with tag=856 and a data field with ind1=4"...